# AWS CLI: Getting total available RDS instances & S3 buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am trying to write a script that would save me going to the web Console every time I need checking how many RDS instances & S3 buckets I can create.

- In the RDS section, there is a DB Instances (20/50) title, I need to get both the 20 and the 50
- In the S3 bucket section, there is the total number of buckets. The implied max number is 100, but my company has increased it to 150. I need the number and the limit (as above).

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use AWS CLI to get all of these values.

> In the RDS section, there is a DB Instances (20/50) title, I need to get both the 20 and the 50

**Get the total number of RDS instances you can create:**

```
aws service-quotas get-service-quota \  
    --service-code rds \  
    --quota-code L-7B6409FD
```

**Get the current number of running RDS instances:**

```
aws rds describe-db-instances --region us-east-1 | grep DBInstanceIdentifier | wc -l
```

> In the S3 bucket section, there is the total number of buckets. The implied max number is 100, but my company has increased it to 150. I need the number and the limit (as above).

**Get the total number of S3 buckets you can create:**

```
aws service-quotas get-service-quota \  
    --service-code s3 \  
    --quota-code L-DC2B2D3D
```

**Get the current number of S3 bucket:**

```
aws s3api list-buckets | grep -w Name | wc -l
```

Comment: It seems that we have different RDS instance/S3 bucket numbers for different roles, and I can't access the service-quotas command for the role that I need the numbers for. For this role for RDS, I can find out the max number from the describe-account-attributes command. Is there anything similar for finding out the quota for S3 by any chance, without using the service-quotas command?

Comment: For the roles, I think you'll need `servicequotas:Get*` access to be able to see the results. There isn't another command that will provide the quota values.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the value of your s3 bucket quota is not available via the AWS API.  The `aws service-quotas` command in Brian's answer will always fail.

```
$ aws service-quotas get-service-quota --service-code s3 --quota-code L-DC2B2D3D

An error occurred (NoSuchResourceException) when calling the GetServiceQuota operation:
```

As of this post, there are only two ways to find your s3 bucket quota:

- File a support ticket and ask for the value
- Look through previous support tickets associated with s3 bucket quota and find the most recently approved quota increase

You can find all quota increase request support tickets for s3 buckets quota by logging into your AWS account and visiting https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/servicequotas/home/services/s3/quotas/L-DC2B2D3D